# Catch the authentication 403 in datasnap proxy generated javascript

Tags: javascript, delphi, rest, basic-authentication, datasnap

There is a browser client, and on the server side a DataSnap REST Server application. I want to authenticate a javascript client. I'm following this guide:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Authentication_with_a_JavaScript_Client

```
...
function doEcho()
  {
    var userName = document.getElementById("namefield"); //get the user name from the form
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordfield"); //get the password from the form

    //create the proxy instance with the specified user credentials
    var Proxy = new TServerMethods1(getAuth(userName, password));
    var Response = Proxy.EchoString("Hello World");

     //Will show an error message if authorization failed,
    //or the JSON Object of parameters if successful
    alert(Response.toJSONString());
  }
...
```

and the problem is that when the username and password credentials are wrong, the Respocnse is just `null`. How can I get more detailed information about what happened such as request status code ?

Have anyone done a javascript authentication with a datasnap rest server application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the JavaScript client actually use basic-authentication? You can verify this with a HTTP proxy such as Fiddler2, or a browser  extension which shows the HTTP traffic including headers.